# ListView Adapter with many different Views

Tags: java, android, performance

This question is more about efficiency than any errors, as I've built this several different ways and haven't been able to reduce lag all around, as each strategy I've tried has its own drawbacks.

So my requirement is that I have a ListView with an unknown, but possibly very large (tens of thousands), amount of data. As I pull in the data, I need to sort the incoming items by both the day it occurs on, as well as the variation of the game it's a part of. Eg.

```
List
    List Item 1
        Date header
        Game 1
            Item
        Game 2
            Item
            Item
            Item
    List Item 2
        Date Header
        Game x 
etc...
```

Since each ListItem can have varying numbers of games with varying numbers of items per game, I can't (or haven't yet found a way to) efficiently reuse the Views using the Adapter to create a smooth scrolling effect.

So here's what I've tried:

1. Inflating a container layout, and then inflating/building the games within the Adapter when its getView() method is called. Clearly inflating the variations each time its called is heavy on the system and does not allow for a smooth experience, even with small amounts of data. However, the choppiness is pretty consistent regardless of the amount of data in the List.
2. Building all the Views before adding to the ListView, and have the Adapter's getView() method simply return the pre-built View. That works very well with smaller amounts of data, but starts to boggle down as more data is added.

My question is, is there a better approach I'm missing or a way to optimize either strategy?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could need something called Holder Pattern.

This looks like a nice tutorial: [http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_holder)

Vogella also touches the subject here: [http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_holder](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

To avoid having to enable scrolling through all of the list, you could also add pagnation, somthing like this library might help: https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/PagingListView

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the Holder Pattern is already implemented as much as physically possible within the requirements, but doesn't work when there are different variations and numbers of Views within that must be individually inflated.

Comment: Just to add to this, with some official docs about it: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html :-)
Also remember you can have different `ViewHolder`'s for the different views. You don't have to make a `one-size-fits-all-ViewHolder`...

Comment: @Darwind thanks, but if I have a different View Holder for each possible List Item, it would be less efficient than me just pre-building the Views and returning the reference in the getView() method like one of the things I listed as already having been tried.

Comment: @Guardanis if you don't that's going to solve it, I suggest you add some code, so we can have a look (and maybe play around with it as well :-))...

Comment: @cYrixmorten thanks again for the edit, but the data is already paginated in terms of how it's pulled in. Paginating the display of the data was my initial approach, but that's just a bandaid and not an actual solution. The requirement is that the ListView is endless.

Comment: @Darwind Thanks for offering, but this isn't an issue of code, this is an issue of approach. And I can't disclose any of the code. But I don't really know what you mean by "that's going to solve it" as your solution is almost exactly identical to the #2 approach I took, with the added deficit of inflation still occurring during the Adapter's display process (thus boggling it down).

Comment: @Guardanis your second approach has nothing to do with the ViewHolder pattern. If you think you're using the ViewHolder pattern by pre-building all views before adding them to the `ListView` this is *excactly* a code-issue... The ViewHolder pattern is about re-using already inflated views, because inflated views are really expensive in Android...

Comment: @Guardanis could you add your `getView` method and your `ViewHolder` class then? :)

Comment: Does the list contain heavy objects such as images? Cause that could be solved by lazy loading, would speed up any heavy views I would think. Only loading them at the point in the list where the user stops scrolling.

Comment: @Darwind nope, each "item" listed above has a varying number of elements that are dynamically defined as they're pulled in. It's not possible to define an efficient ViewHolder Pattern for the individual "items", nor their "game" containers due to the variations in sizes and lengths. even if it were, that would be the same as an approach I've already tried.

Comment: @cYrixmorten There are no "images" aside from the xml ShapeDrawables loaded as the View's background, and all images throughout the rest of the app are already-lazy-loaded.

Comment: @Guardanis so EVERY item varies? Then you might have to keep the size of the list down and remove items, when they're not in sight. Then when the items comes in sight again, you add them back ind and remove the old ones... that way you'd keep the list tiny and crisp...

Comment: @Darwind Yes, every single item and every single game container varies in size. Removing and re-adding them would be worse on the system as it would still be inflating every time getView() is called, with the added overhead of managing the additions/removal of the items

Comment: @Guardanis hmmm, the plot thickens ;-) What about checking for if the user scrolls (fast) and if he/she scrolls fast, don't try to load the "expensive" items until the scrolling has slowed down or stopped completely? The user doesn't see the items anyway...

Comment: @Darwind Since the data is entirely dynamic and will always vary, the system would have to traverse the data to determine what is actually "expensive" which would probably be just as heavy. Plus it's not just an issue of scrolling quickly. But thanks for still trying to help!

Comment: @Guardanis no problem - sorry I couldn't be of more help. Last thing: how about building the views in an `AsyncTask` as described in this post: http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/ <-- scroll down to "Async loading".

Comment: @Darwin Thanks, but that's exactly what I already did with #2. I tried pre-building all the Views, which worked very well for small amounts of data :)